# StackNavigation from ExNavigation : unbale to do navigation

Tags: react-native, exponentjs

I am using StackNavigation from @exponent/ex-navigation lib. Everything works fine. But push() or pop() does not to any animation. I have tried setting following for same

```
<StackNavigation
    defaultRouteConfig={{
        navigationBar: {
            backgroundColor: Colors.appThemeColor,
            tintColor: 'whitesmoke',
        }
    }}
    configScene={ExNavigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight}
    initialRoute={Router.getRoute('locator')} />

 configScene={ExNavigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight} was not able to render scene with animation.
```

Please let me know if i am missing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed, was setting animation at wrong place. Set it at Scene with required navigation style

```
static route = {
 styles: NavigationStyles.FloatHorizontal,
}
```